# ELIF statements skipped in favor of ELSE

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a few statements utilizing regular expressions to match an output to a given extension.  My For loop seems to work fine, I get an answer back for each of the files and if I take one out or add one, I get a return.
What appears to happen though is that my first file is picked up, matched successfully, and the correct output given.  The loop then grabs the next file, checks against the first statement, then skips the two ELIF's and gives and output based on my ELSE.  Can anyone point out why or if I have it wrong, what is actually going on?

```
def extmatch():

    global dircontents

    for file in dircontents:
        dircontents = re.search(".+\sbreakout.*\.ttx", file)

        if dircontents:
            print('File is for TIA')

        elif dircontents:
            dircontents = re.search('\w+\.csv+$', file)

            if dircontents:
                print('File is for NMFTA')

        elif dircontents:
            dircontents = re.search('\w+.\.txt+$', file)

            if dircontents:
                print('File is for NMFTA')

        else:
            print('File type not recognized.')
```

`['061419license breakout_ibc_v3_0116.ttx', '2019-06-17_7-49-21.jpg', 'SampleCSV.csv', 'script_test.txt']`  <--- these are the files in the dir indicated

> File is for TIA
>
> File type not recognized.  <---Seems to match to ELSE for each file past the first
>
> File type not recognized.
>
> File type not recognized.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this code doesn't make much sense. If the first `if dircontents` check fails, so will all the rest that come after it, and the `else` will be entered.

Comment: Your condition for the `if` and both `elif`s is just `dircontents`, so they all have the same truth value. You need to have the result of the `re.search()` as the condition, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You're altering `dircontents` while iterating over it.  Don't do that.  Use different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
def extmatch(dircontents):
    for filename in dircontents:
        if filename.lower().endswith(".ttx"):
            print('File is for TIA')
        elif filename.lower().endswith(".csv"):
            print('File is for NMFTA')
        elif filename.lower().endswith(".txt"):
            print('File is for NMFTA')
        else:
            print('File type not recognized.')
```

or even like this:

```
EXT_ASSIGNMENTS = {
    'ttx': 'TIA',
    'csv': 'NMFTA',
    'txt': 'NMFTA',
}

def extmatch(dircontents):
    for filename in dircontents:
        ext = filename.lower().split('.')[-1]
        if ext in EXT_ASSIGNMENTS:
            print('File is for ' + EXT_ASSIGNMENTS[ext])
        else:
            print('File type not recognized.')
```

Avoid global variables. If you need to pass information to a function, use an argument.

Comment: That definitely did the job, can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Missed them somehow, I'm square. TY